space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':' in SpEL support in Spring Data JPA @Query definitions
I need to update the values into update native query from EmployeeDTO class and I have used following implemetation. But I got this error in console, even though the syntax is correct for query:

Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':'

Entity class:
@NamedNativeQuery( name = "Employee.updateEmployeeRecord", 
    query = "update employee set first_name = :#{#emp.firstName}, last_name = :#{#emp.lastName}, " +    
                "address = :#{#emp.address} where id = :#{#emp.id}"
)
@Entity
public class Employee {

 //codes
}

DTO class:
public class EmployeeDTO {

    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
    
// getter and setters
}

Repository class:
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {

  @Query(name = "Employee.updateEmployeeRecord", nativeQuery = true)
  void updateEmployeeRecord(@Params("emp") EmployeeDTO empDto);
}

Service Implementation class - update statement:
employeeRepository.updateEmployeeRecord(empDto);

Why it is throwing error even the syntax and query are correct? How can I solve it?

As I tried, The Spring Expression Language(SpEL) does not support for @NamedNativeQuery. So I wrote the same query within @Query annotation in the repository method and I removed the NamedNativeQuery. As I expected It worked for me!
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {

  @Query(value = "update employee set first_name = :#{#emp.firstName}, last_name = :#{#emp.lastName}, address = :#{#emp.address} where id = :#{#emp.id}", nativeQuery = true)
  void updateEmployeeRecord(@Params("emp") EmployeeDTO empDto);
}

